# How add new <input> when the last input has a value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I started to make a form - [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-add-input-v2?file=src/app/dynamicform/dynamicform.component.html), but I do not know how to proceed further

I want to make the same effect as here: 
[image: RESTer addons]
shown in the picture implemented as follows: [github - RESTer](https://github.com/frigus02/RESTer/blob/7007577676e15e26790ef599d696b2e2d0bf0ca0/src/site/elements/controls/rester-header-input.html#L144)

I tried with the method (change) but it works after pressing Enter, that does not suit me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `input` event on the last line:

```
<div *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index; let isLast = last" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="25px">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name-{{i}}" value="{{header.name}}" 
           (input)="addInput(isLast)">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
    <input matInput placeholder="Value" type="text" name="value-{{i}}" value="{{header.value}}">
  </mat-form-field>
  ...
</div>
```

with the `addInput` method, which adds a new record the first time the input content changes:

```
export class DynamicformComponent implements OnInit {

  public headers: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headers = [
      { name: 'Accept-Encoding', value: 'gzip' },
      { name: 'Accept-Charset', value: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'User-Agent', value: '' },
      { name: 'Accept', value: 'text/plain' },
      { name: 'Cookie', value: '' },
      { name: '', value: '' }
    ];
  }

  addInput(isLast: boolean) {
    if (isLast) {
      this.headers.push({ name: '', value: '' });
    }
  }

  removeInput(index) {
    this.headers.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-add-input-v2-brgwjs) for a demo.

Comment: why not use < (input)="addInput(isLast)">? (and forget (focus))

Comment: @Eliseo - Thanks for the suggestion! It makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use formArray, if you use reactive forms. have a look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays